# Find the values of $p$ where $\cos x - 2px$ is invertible

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm sorry that I posted a homework question.I just couldn't find answers properly.

I attempted in the following way:

- To prove that it is invertible it's enough to prove that it is bijective
- To prove that it is bijective we have to prove that it is both injective and surjective
- I can prove injectivity by proving that it is a strictly monotonous function( Not sure about this concept also) and then get values of $ p $
- I don't know if showing that it is monotonous for certain values of $p$ is good enough to prove it's surjectivity

Could you help me in proving it's surjectivity and also help me understand if proving strictly monotonocity is enough for injectivity or not

Any little help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is strictly monotonous then for all $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$ you have
$$x>y\ \Rightarrow\ f(x)>f(y),$$
from which it easily follows that $f(x)=f(y)\ \Rightarrow\ x=y$, so indeed $f$ is injective.

So $f$ is invertible whenever $p$ is such that $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$, or such that $f'(x)<0$ for all $x$. This still leaves some values of $p$ unresolved though. As this is homework, I'll leave it to you (for now) to figure out what happens then.

**EDIT:** Because $f'(x)=\sin(x)-2p$, if $p>\frac12$ then $f'(x)<0$, and if $p<-\frac12$ then $f'(x)>0$. Hence $f(x)$ is invertible for these values of $p$.

If $-\frac12<p<\frac12$ then $f'(0)>0$ and $f'(\pi)<0$. This means $f$ is not invertible (why?).

Then the only remaining cases are $p=\frac12$ and $p=-\frac12$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still couldn't find a way for checking it's surjectivity...could you help me with that?